# not able to get getExpressionFactory method in jsf 1.2_12

Tags: jsf

I am using jsf 1.2_12, here i am not able to find Method Expression or getExpressionFactory in Facescontext.getcurrentInstance().getApplication. What could be the problem. kindly help.

Comment: it's quite there ;) _how_ are you unable to get it?

Comment: Yes i check with decompiler but when i use CTRL+TAB i am not getting it ...

Comment: And when you write it, it doesn't compile?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting your question, any way when write FacesContext.getcurrentInstance.getapplication... after that i am not getting the getExpressionfactory method

Comment: and I don't get yours ;) do you get a compile-time error? Do you get a run-time problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like as if your IDE is configured to use JSF 1.1 API and that you expect JSF 1.2 methods to appear in the autocomplete. Well, an IDE is *just* a tool. Configure it to use JSF 1.2 or just enter the methods in yourself.

This problem is not related to JSF. Again, an IDE is *just a tool*. It is not part of Java/JSF or so.